# How to generate a file format like this (javascript array??) ?? in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, amcharts

Is this possible to generate a file format like below in PHP? Because I am gonna use this in my chart. So somebody please help me, any help will be appreciated.

```
[{
"title": "Marketing",       /* This is a code from a sample in chart */
"value": 23,                /* The sample chart of link is below */
"url":"#",
"description":"click to drill-down",
"data": [
{ "title": "Jan", "value": 1, "data": [
  { "title": "AAA", "value": 2 },
  { "title": "BBB", "value": 5 },
  { "title": "CCC", "value": 1 },
] },
{ "title": "Feb", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Mar", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Apr", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "May", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Jun", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Jul", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Aug", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Sep", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Oct", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Nov", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Dec", "value": 3 }
]
}, {
"title": "Sales",
"value": 26,
"url":"#",
"description":"click to drill-down",
"data": [
{ "title": "Jan", "value": 4 },
{ "title": "Feb", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Mar", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Apr", "value": 4 },
{ "title": "May", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Jun", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Jul", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Aug", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Sep", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Oct", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Nov", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Dec", "value": 3 }
 ]
}, {
"title": "Logistics",
"value": 30,
"url":"#",
"description":"click to drill-down",
"data": [
{ "title": "Jan", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Feb", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Mar", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Apr", "value": 5 },
{ "title": "May", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Jun", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Jul", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Aug", "value": 2 },
{ "title": "Sep", "value": 3 },
{ "title": "Oct", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Nov", "value": 1 },
{ "title": "Dec", "value": 3 }
]
}];
```

Link of Sample Chart that ive been studying with..
http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c5ea20211ef3a5151480e88ed680dcb8

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need function `json_encode()` to format `PHP Array` become `JSON` like that. But make sure your PHP Installation has Json Extension (`php-json`)

```
$array = [
    [
        'title' => 'Marketing',
        'value' => 23,
        'url' => '#',
        'description' => 'click to drill-down',
        'data' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Jan',
                'value' => 1,
                'data'  => [
                    ['title' => 'AAA', 'value' => 2],
                    ['title' => 'BBB', 'value' => 5],
                    ['title' => 'CCC', 'value' => 1],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Feb',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Mar',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Apr',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'May',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Jun',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Jul',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Aug',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Sep',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Oct',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Nov',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Des',
                'value' => 2
            ],
        ]
   ],
   [
        'title' => 'Logistic',
        'value' => 30,
        'url' => '#',
        'description' => 'click to drill-down',
        'data' => [
        ]

   ]
];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but what if my data that should be in that json format is from my PHP file that retreiving the result from mySQL.?

Comment: Use looping (`while`, `foreach`) and compose  `php array` inside looping

Answer (score 0):

> You can generate JSON Data directly in PHP. It wouldn't matter at all if you are fetching your Data from a Database or via some Web-Service or whether you are simply dynamically building it yourself. The principle is the same. Once you got your Final Data: *For example a Result-Set from the Database*, you can simply call the Function `json_encode()` on that Data... That's all there is to it....

```
<?php

    // ASSUMING YOU PERFORMED SOME DATABASE TRANSACTIONS AND FINALLY
    // YOUR RESULT-SET (CONSISTING OF AN ARRAY OF ROWS) LOOKS LIKE THIS:
    $resultSet   = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      

    // YOU MIGHT PROCESS THE RESULT FURTHER THROUGH A LOOP OR WHATEVER  
    // HOWEVER, ONCE YOU ARE DONE PROCESSING, YOU MAY NOW GENERATE THE JSON DATA
    $jsonData     = json_encode($resultSet);
```

Comment: What do you mean when specify the second argument for `json_encode` as `true`?

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i already got what i need. i have new problem but not related to my question.

Comment: @Emjey23   And what would that be? Ask away....  SO has a bunch of ready, smart heads to spare.... ;-)

Comment: @Poiz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903881/how-to-make-my-chartdata-dynamic-using-my-valid-local-filejson